# Permutation and Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, convex-analysis

A function $G$ is defined on a set $S$ with size $k$ : $G(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k)$.
$G(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k) = 1$ if and only if a convex polygon can be created by taking these $k$ elements as the side lengths. Otherwise $G(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k) = 0$.
You are given the identity permutation over $n$ elements - $I_n(I_n=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\})$.
Find the sum of function $G$ over all possible distinct $k$-sized subsets of $I_n$.

All I could think of involved checking all subsets of size $k$ (which is not efficient for large size of the set obviously).Checking the $G$ value for a subset is easy , you just check if the largest element is greater than the sum of all other or not. Calculating the *number* of such subsets doesn't seem trivial :/ I wonder if there is some pattern/theorem/recurrence involved.

Comment: I'd say that it's sufficient and necessary that the largest elemen is less than the sum of the others...

Comment: For triangles, see http://oeis.org/A002620.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions are important here.

Let's start by assuming $k\ge 1$ here so ignoring a whether a polygon with no sides exists.  Let's also assume that a convex polygon has positive area, so the subset $\{1,2,3\}$ produces a degenerate triangle and is not counted, while the subset $\{1,2,3,4\}$ can produce essentially several convex quadrilaterals but we will count it once. As leonboy commented, it is necessary and sufficient that the largest element a subset is strictly smaller than the sum of the others.  That will not happen if $k <3$ and not  when $n=k=3$.

Here is a table for small $n,k$:

```
 n \ k [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0    1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    3    5    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    7   14    6    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0   13   32   21    7     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0   22   63   56   28     8     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [9,]    0    0   34  112  126   84    36     9     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
[10,]    0    0   50  185  251  210   120    45    10     1     0     0     0     0     0
[11,]    0    0   70  289  459  462   330   165    55    11     1     0     0     0     0
[12,]    0    0   95  431  785  924   792   495   220    66    12     1     0     0     0
[13,]    0    0  125  620 1273 1716  1716  1287   715   286    78    13     1     0     0
[14,]    0    0  161  865 1976 3003  3432  3003  2002  1001   364    91    14     1     0
[15,]    0    0  203 1176 2959 5004  6435  6435  5005  3003  1365   455   105    15     1
```

The third column is essentially [OEIS A002623](https://oeis.org/A002623) offset and its first difference is, as Alexander Burstein commented, [OEIS A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620).

My reading of the question is that you are interested in the numbers for $n$, i.e. the row sums.  This starts $$0,   0,     0,     2,     9,    28,    74,   178,   402,   872,  1842,  3821,  7830, 15913, 32161, 64761,   130091,   260911$$ which does not seem to appear in OEIS but seems to be the difference between two sequences which do: [A095941](https://oeis.org/A095941) (which would also count cases where the polygons are of zero area) and [OEIS A317910](https://oeis.org/A317910) (which seems to only count cases where the polygons are of zero area).

The various OEIS links suggest a relationship between this sequence and the number of ways of partitioning $n$ into distinct parts [OEIS A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009); its generating function is $\prod\limits_{m\ge1} (1+x^m)$ while the generating function of this sequence seems to be $$\frac{1-x-x^2}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \prod\limits_{m\ge1} (1+x^m)$$